# MYSQL server ip does not work the same way as localhost

Tags: mysql

Lets say the ip of our server is 55.555.555.55. Lets also say we have a mysql user that is `'user'@'localhost'`

**So then, why does this return a permission error**

```
$mysql_server = "55.555.555.55";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_db = "";
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connection failed: %s \n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

**But this does not**

```
$mysql_server = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_db = "";
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connection failed: %s \n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Isn't 55.555.555.55 and localhost the same thing? It shouldn't be a issue.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 and localhost are the same thing. I don't know about 5555555 though

Comment: This ip 55.555.555.55 is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `localhost` is treated by MySQL as a bypass to TCP/IP.  It uses the UNIX socket.  And you need two rows in your `mysql.user` privileges table to authorize these two access methods, even if the username and password is the same.

The wildcard `'%'` matches any IP address or hostname, but it does *not* match localhost.  This may be counter-intuitive, but it's the way MySQL works.

This is explained here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html

Comment: Bill Karwin folks. As always, great answer. Its thanks to you btw that I was able to understand a little bit about Polymorphism in databases.